# How to get p-value from calculation of TCGAanalyze_survival in R language

Tags: r

I have one problem when I tried to get the p value from `TCGAanalyze_survival` in R lanuage.

I can see there is p value in document /home/lance/Downloads/testWorkSpace/test12/figure/surv_analysis/survival_analysis03.pdf.

The p value is 0.00036,but I can not get the value from variable in code .

```r
TCGAanalyze_survival(survivalInfo, clusterCol = "hc", color = c("#33A02C","#1F78B4","#E31A1C"), filename = "/home/lance/Downloads/testWorkSpace/test12/figure/surv_analysis/survival_analysis03.pdf", conf.int = F, width = 7, height = 7)

result <- TCGAanalyze_survival(survivalInfo, clusterCol = "hc", color = c("#33A02C","#1F78B4","#E31A1C"), filename = NULL, conf.int = F, width = 7, height = 7)
print(result)
attributes(result)
```

And I used attributes(result) to check the attributes of result, but there is no attribute about p value

could someone provide any suggestion and hint?

I took a look at the attributes of result

```
> attributes(result)
$names
[1] "plot"           "table"          "data.survplot"  "data.survtable"

$class
[1] "ggsurvplot" "ggsurv"     "list"      

$heights
$heights$plot
[1] 0.75

$heights$table
[1] 0.25

$heights$ncensor.plot
[1] 0

$heights$cumevents
[1] 0


$y.text
$y.text$table
[1] TRUE

$y.text$cumevents
[1] TRUE

$y.text$cumcensor
[1] TRUE


$y.text.col
$y.text.col$table
[1] TRUE

$y.text.col$cumevents
[1] TRUE

$y.text.col$cumcensor
[1] TRUE


$legend.position
[1] "top"    "bottom" "left"   "right"  "none"  

$legend.labs
            1             2 
"1 (n = 383)"  "2 (n = 70)" 

$cumcensor
[1] FALSE

$risk.table.pos
[1] "out"

$axes.offset
[1] TRUE
```

Then use the code to output

```r
p_value <- result$logrank$pval
p_value <- result$pval
```

but the result is null

Answer (score 0):

Currently,I used this method:

```
library(pdftools)
text <- pdf_text("/home/lance/Downloads/testWorkSpace/test12/figure/surv_analysis/survival_analysis03.pdf")
#matches <- grep("p < 0\\.[0-9]+", text, value = TRUE)
#print(matches)
#matches1<- grep("\\b[p]\\s*<\\s*0\\.0001\\b",text, value = TRUE)
#print(matches1)
#p<0\\.[0-9]+
matches_locations <- gregexpr("p < 0\\.[0-9]+", text)
matches <- regmatches(text, matches_locations)
#print(matches)
numeric_value <- sub("p\\s*<\\s*", "", matches)
#print(numeric_value)
numeric_value <- as.numeric(numeric_value)
print(numeric_value)
```

Then I can get the value from p.

The p value can be obtained from the document instead of being gotten from function TCGAanalyze_survival